# Send JSON array as a parameter Alamofire

Tags: swift, alamofire

I'm having difficulty with a parameter which contains a Json array using Alamofire

Here is a string of my Json:

```
"[{\"id\":546836102,\"count\":1},{\"id\":216479424,\"count\":1}]"
```

Here is my code where I make the request:

```
let data = (params["cart"] as! String).data(using: .utf8)!
do {
    if let jsonArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options : .fragmentsAllowed) as? [Dictionary<String, Int>] {

       let parameters: Parameters = [
           "address_id": params["address_id"] as! Int,
           "delivery_day": params["delivery_day"] as! String,
           "delivery_hour": params["delivery_hour"] as! Int,
           "cart": jsonArray,
           "via": params["via"] as! String
       ]

       Alamofire.request(Global.baseURL + "orders/finish", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: header)
                .responseSwiftyJSON {
```

Printing out my `parameters`

```
["cart": [["id": 546836102, "count": 1], ["count": 1, "id": 216479424]], "address_id": 641589205, "delivery_day": "1399-01-20", "delivery_hour": 21, "via": "ios"]
```

Backend must receive the `cart` as below:

```
[
 {
  "id": 123456,
  "count": 2
 },
 {
  "id": 654321,
  "count": 3
 }
]
```

But instead it gets the data like this:

```
{
 "delivery_hour" : "21",
 "delivery_day" : "1399-01-20",
 "cart" : [
  {
   "count" : "1"
  },
  {
   "id" : "546836102"
  },
  {
   "count" : "1"
  },
  {
   "id" : "216479424"
  }
 ],
 "via" : "ios",
 "address_id" : "641589205"
}
```

I have tried JSONEncoding and URLEncoding options by Alamofire but nothing seems to work and this is the closest I've gotten to the API template so far.

What am I doing so wrong here?

```
// MARK: - Update
```

So I updated to the latest version of Alamofire and still no good results :(
Here is the code:

```
let payload = MyParameters(address_id: 641589205, delivery_day: "1399-01-21", delivery_hour: 21, cart: items, via: "ios")

AF.request(url, method: .post, parameters: payload, encoder: JSONParameterEncoder.default, headers: .init(header), interceptor: nil).response { dataResponse in
        switch dataResponse.result {
        case .success(let value):
            if dataResponse.response?.statusCode == 200 {
                let json = JSON(value!)
                completionHandler(json, nil)
            } else {
                print(dataResponse.response?.statusCode ?? -1)
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
            completionHandler(nil, error.localizedDescription)
        }
}
```

My `payload` looks exactly what I want it to be

```
{
  "cart" : [
    {
      "count" : 1,
      "id" : 546836102
    },
    {
      "count" : 1,
      "id" : 216479424
    }
  ],
  "via" : "ios",
  "address_id" : 641589205,
  "delivery_day" : "1399-01-21",
  "delivery_hour" : 21
}
```

But then again the endpoint receives this:

```
{
  "{\"delivery_day\":\"1399-01-21\",\"address_id\":641589205,\"delivery_hour\":21,\"cart\":" : {
"{\"id\":546836102,\"count\":1},{\"id\":216479424,\"count\":1}" : null
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Alamofire 4, you can't send arrays using the method you've shown, as the `Parameters` type is `[String: Any]`. You're also not using the correct `ParameterEncoding`. If you want to send a JSON body, you need to use the `JSONEncoding`. What you can do is manually serialize the array into a `URLRequest` and make that request using Alamofire.

Additionally, if you update to Alamofire 5, `Encodable` parameters are now supported, so you if you can define your parameters as an `Encodable` type, sending them would be as easy as passing an array.

```swift
AF.request(..., parameters: [some, encodable, values], encoder: JSONEncoder.default)...
```

Comment: I've updated and went through this tutorial (https://www.stencia.com/blog/2019/8/18/post-using-alamofire-5) and still not the expected results. I updated my original post with the new code